# How to make MdDialog drag-able(Movable) in Angular 2 Material Design

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I am creating a small web app using Angular2 and Its Material Design(https://material.angular.io) In which I am using MdDialog to show dialog box using following code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result.html',
})
export class DialogResult {
  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Dialog);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.selectedOption = result;
    });
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.html',
})
export class Dialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<Dialog>) {}
}
```

**I want to make the dialog box draggable or movable using a mouse so that I can also see my page content.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Draggabilly library.

when open a dialog component, pass a costume 'panelClass' in options:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Dialog, {
    panelClass: 'dialog-container'
});
```

Then, initial draggablilly in dialog component ngOnInit hook:

```
const holder = new draggablilly('.dialog-container');
```

Comment: Share link on dragging library